# MVC: trying to understand where ActionResult sends it's data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have been trying to understand an online tutorial and I am stumped.
Can someone please tell me where the text "Hello" is sent to? Is the message sent directly to the browser without being placed on a page?

public class GoHomeController : Controller

```
{
    public string Index()
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
}
```

Comment: that is not an `ActionResult` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How's this?  Your controller action needs to have a return type of `ActionResult`, there are many subclasses of this class that allow for various types of responses however you can always influence with brute force if you like.  For example"

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
   Response.Write("hello world");
   return null;
}
```

The above code writes to the Response stream directly, in my example I return a null. This indicates no ActionResult is needed to be performed by the MVC system, typically this is where the View is specified, the View will be read, parsed and written to the Response stream as well.

But typical controller actions do have return values, for example here is how I could return JSON, remember the View is just an abstraction to allow you to control what is written to the `Response` stream.

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 

   return Json( new { Message="Hello world"});
}
```

And then there is the typical ActionResult that directs the output to a .cshtml file:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
   return View();
}
```

This will write to the `Response` stream using the `Index.cshtml` file tied to this controller namespace or I could specify the name of the .cshtml:

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{ 
   return View("HelloWorld");   //<-- looks for HelloWorld.cshtml
}
```

Comment: Fantastic information. I will have to digest it. I had to reformat my code so it looked readable. I guess my disconnect is: if you just return a string, how does the text wind up on a browser? In my example I could not find any file for the browser to process. Can the browser read directly from the response stream?

Comment: yes, the server side C# code writes to the `Response` stream and that is what is rendered in the browser.